# Modelling open water flow in TIN-model using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, tin, flow, waterways, hec-georas

I have a [TIN-model created from 1800 xyz-coordinates](http://s11.postimg.org/p8fizl6hf/Example_Render_Fillerup.png) (that I also have). There is an pipe leading all the water in and on for all the water out.

I would very much like to simulate movement of the water under different volumes of water flowing into the system.

Any bright ideas?

I already tried HEC-RAS / HEC-GeoRAS but it doesn't work with ARC 10.3 which is the only version I can get from my university.

Comment: You can't specifically model water flow (unless there's a plugin I've missed) in ArcGIS. What you can do is to see which areas will be flooded when the water reaches a certain level, and with some extra work you can base this on volumes (in steady-state). If you need to model overland water flow and floods you need something like HecRAS or Mike21. However, as you noted, none of them works with ArcGIS 10.3 (10.1 is required for Mike).

Comment: I hoped you wouldn't say that :) Guess I have to find another approach.